# Algorithm to order edges around a vertex in 3D, counterclockwise

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

How to order line segments (edges in the mesh) around a vertex counterclockwise with respect to the vertex?

As shown in the uploaded image, points are not necessarily planar. Basically, consider moving on outside surface of a complex meshed object, at any vertex I want to order connecting edges (to that vertex) to be ordered counterclockwise regardless of the surface local condition, convexity or concavity.

The algorithm needs to be short and fast, so can be implemented and used for huge mesh.

I am not interested in any package, library or software. I will implemented it by myself. Only a working algorithm is of my interest.

EDIT:
To make the question clearer, I add that, for every vertex I have a list of connecting edges (and so vertices), already. The purpose is to order the list of surrounding vertices such that connecting those sequentially will create a polygon (ring) not-self-intersecting and "overall" counterclockwise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWEVj.png)

Comment: Do you want the one-ring of a given vertex? What data structure do you have?

Comment: (Looking at the image) does this mean you're only interested in `(x, z)` dimensions and not `y`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler for every vertex I have already a list of connected edges.

Comment: @גלעדברקן No. All coordinates are of great importance, since the surface mesh can be very complicated. Consider an organic body, for example. The shape of the thing made of the central vertex and connected vertices can be any form, such as narrow wedge or a widened polyhedron etc.

Comment: The edges alone won't help you too much. Do you also have the triangles per vertex?

Comment: The notion of "counterclockwise" needs to be defined with respect to some direction. In 3D space you can view a "counterclockwise" arrangement from "the other side", and it would look like "clockwise".

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can't. (Think of the center of a tetrahedron and the four edges to the vertices.)

For a meshed surface, we may assume that you know the normal at every vertex. Then you can project the edges onto the tangent plane (using a local frame) and solve the ordering problem in 2D.

If you don't know the normals, you can resort to plane fitting, but as there is a direction ambiguity, you have to enforce normal direction coherence.

Comment: I don't get it why "cannot". You have a central vertex, and all connected edges to it. You start with any of those, next you go to another one, and you do that until you reach your start point, a ring. Physically, it makes sense to me. But I have no clear idea of an algorithm that can efficiently do the job.